# How to overlay an image on my border in Android using XML?

Tags: android, xml, layout, overlay

I want to  add an image on a border that I created using **shape** in XML. The border is shown at the bottom of my view. I want to add an image(icon) in the center of this border, it has to overlay the border and the height of the image is more than the border. It has to look like this:

[image]

This is my border.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#383839" />

            <solid android:color="#383839" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#383839" />

            <solid android:color="#383839" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And this is what I tried in my `layout.xml`:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but this just let everything disappear in my mainLayout.

Comment: Don't you miss the **xmlns** in your RelativeLayout??

Comment: there is the mainLayout above the RelativeLayout which contains the xmlns

Comment: OK, I couldn't imagine that... Also note that your ImageView can be "inserted" into the TextView (it's a best practice, to use compound drawables): use `android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_icon"` and give `android:drawablePadding` a value in dp, to separate it from the text.